# Glue gun series dropping capacitor

Tags: capacitor, transformerless, ptc

I have a 40 W on label glue gun for 230 V socket, PTC element could be 20 W as some manufacturers use 20 W instead and label it as 40W .
I want to add a voltage dropping capacitor to increase its durability.
Should I add 1 uF, 1.5 uF or 2.2 uF capacitor, should I choose 250 volts non polar capacitor or higher voltage one?
I have few 0.1 uF 400 V, 1 uF 250 V.

Comment: how are you going to add the capacitor to the glue gun?

Comment: What did your simulations and or calculations show?

Comment: _"40 W glue gun for 230 V socket, PTC element could be 20 W"_ This does not make any sense. What makes up the remaining 20 W?

Comment: Some Manufacturers  label it as  40 watts while the element could be 20 watts

Comment: Should be illegal.

Comment: Your glue will be cooler and things are more likely to get clogged up ,and the glue will take ages to warm up and run

Comment: @jsotola connect your glue gun power cord in series with a 2.2uf /400v cap and tell me.